# How to use months in a sentence? For example: ＂January＂

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I've always thought that to use the month in a sentence you must use it with a preposition, such as "*... at January*"． But I saw a sentence in a press release today:

> ＂Nearly two-thirds of New York restaurants could be out of business as
> soon as **January** without some sort of additional government aid,
> according to a new study＂.

In this sentence "*January*" is not used with a preposition (e.g., "*at January*"), but instead with the phrase" *as soon as* ".

Why is this?

Can I use "*as soon as at January*" or "*at January*" instead of "*as soon as January*" in this sentence?

Comment: We never say _at January_ - it's _in January_.

Comment: @KateBunting，I see , thank you for reminding me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "as soon as January" is correct as it is. "As soon as at January" isn't idiomatic.

Here is a dictionary that shows "as soon as" as a conjunction when it is followed by a clause, and as a preposition when it is followed by a noun.
[Wiktionary "as soon as"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_soon_as)

> conjunction
> *I came as soon as I could.*
> preposition
> *He might arrive as soon as three o'clock.*

Some other words about time, such as *before* and *after* are also categorized as conjunctions in some uses, and prepositions in other uses.

Comment: Jack, this phrasing sounds quite odd - "as soon as January". Not sure why anyone would choose "as soon as" there instead of "by".

Comment: This phrasing is commonly used, and it is done to emphasise what lies between the first 'as' and the second. If we say that something might happen **as soon as** January, we are emphasising how **soon** that is. If we say that some pine trees can be **as tall as** 80 metres, we are emphasising how **tall** they can be.

Comment: @Jack，You gave a very clear answer，thank you ！